# Relationship returning NULL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web, eloquent

Im very new to Laravel.
I want to display the data i needed and i create a relationship to my tables but its not working. Can you find any of my mistakes?

i have two tables **Users** and **Places**

**Users Model**

```
protected $fillable = array('name', 'email', 'password','role','places_id');

public function places(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Places');
}
```

**Places Model**

```
protected $fillable = array('name','email','phone','address','bio');

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

**Controller**

```
 $users = User::with('Places')->get();
 return view('/dashboard')->with('users',$users);
```

**The output is**

```
Collection {#121 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => User {#322 ▶}
    1 => User {#323 ▶}
    2 => User {#324 ▼
      #fillable: array:5 [▶]
      #hidden: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "users"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:10 [▶]
      #original: array:10 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "Places" => null
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is not working? From where I'm standing everything seems to be fine.

Comment: the relationship "Places" are returning NULL, i want it to return the data

Answer (score 4):

I think you have your relations swapped. It is the other way around:

Users model:

```
public function places()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Places');
}
```

A *User* has the foreign key `places_id`, so a *User* does not belong to a place, but *has* a place.

Places model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

A *Place* does not have a user, but instead belongs *to* a User. I know it is confusing in the beginning, but you'll surely get the hang of it! You can use this 'trick' to help you (at least that's how I remember it all the time):

*Name of Model* 'relationship' *name of function*

---

Addition / update after new comment of original poster (with foreign keys):

Users model:

```
public function places()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Places', 'places_id', 'id');
}
```

Places model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'places_id', 'id');
}
```

The format for a relationship is `('Model Name', 'foreign key', 'local key')`.

Comment: This give me an error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'places.user_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Can you post your table structures in your original question please? (Just for completeness). I think you need to specify the foreign key in the Places model if you named some columns differently, in the users() function: `return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'places_id', 'id');`

Comment: Places Table [id,name,email,phone,address,bio)
Users Table [id,name,email,password,role,places_id)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I updated my answer. Can you try to use that?

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Tho i didnt change the hasMany and belongsTo for each function, i just added the 'foreign key' and 'local key'. Thanks a lot.